# Hoelder's inequality for measurable functions alone?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, holder-inequality

Are their examples where hölders inequality can't be applied to just measurable functions i.e.
if $f$ and $g$ are measurable and $fg$ integrable, but $f$ may be not in $L^p$ or $g$ may be not in $L^q$ ($\frac{1}{q}+\frac{1}{p}=1$) can I still conclude that

$\|fg\|_1\leq \|f\|_p \|g\|_q$ ?

Comment: If neither $f$, nor $g$ are zero almost everywhere, then $\Vert f\Vert_p, \Vert g\Vert_q>0$. Hence, if $f\notin L^p$ or $g\notin L^q$, then that just means $\Vert f\Vert_p=\infty$, respectively $\Vert g\Vert_q=\infty$ and Hölder's inequality just says $\Vert fg\Vert_1<\infty$. So, Hölder holds true, but does not tell us anything interesting.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven you're right but Im just worried if the proof then is still applicable. Since the theorem is often stated in a way where it is required that $f,g$ are in $L^p$,$L^q$

Comment: I am confused, there is nothing to prove. You assume $fg\in L^1$, thus $\Vert fg\Vert_1<\infty=\Vert f\Vert_p \Vert g\Vert_q$ if $f\notin L^p$ or $g\notin L^q$ (and none of $f,g$ is zero almost everywhere).

Comment: Oh, I see. The "usual" proof does not apply here if that is what you mean. However, the one-line proof in my previous comment takes care of the Hölder inequality in this special case.

Comment: The quesstion should maybe be why is it required in the statement of Hölder inequality that $f\in L^p$$g\in \L^q$. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: It is usually required, to get the (stronger) statement $f\in L^p, g\in L^q$ implies $fg\in L^1$. We do not want to assume that $fg\in L^1$. However, if you assume it, then you can drop the $L^p, L^q$ requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If neither $f$, nor $g$ are zero almost everywhere, then $\Vert f\Vert_p, \Vert g\Vert_q>0$. Hence, if $f\notin L^p$ or $g\notin L^q$, then that just means $\Vert f\Vert_p=\infty$, respectively $\Vert g\Vert_q=\infty$ and Hölder's inequality just says $\Vert fg\Vert_1<\infty =\Vert f\Vert_p \Vert g\Vert_q$. So, Hölder holds true, but does not tell us anything interesting.

If $f$ is zero almost everywhere and $g\notin L^q$, then the problem is that the RHS of Hölder's inequality is "$0\cdot \infty$" and so we would need to make sense of that first.

The reason why we typically assume $f\in L^p, g\in L^q$ is to make sure that $fg\in L^1$. We do not want to assume $fg\in L^1$ (in a way that is "Hölder inequality light").